# ListView selected item to TextBox

Tags: c#, listview, textbox

First, I have filled a list object with the data from xml file. After that, I have filled a `ListView` with the necessary fields, without any problem. How can I get the index from the selected `ListView` item and then give appropriate value to some textbox?

This is the code for it:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    List<Tasks> taskList = new List<Tasks>();

    listView1.Columns.Add("Date:");
    listView1.Columns.Add("Job:");
    listView1.Columns.Add("Client Name");
    listView1.Columns.Add("Submitted by");

    taskList = getTasks();

    listView1.Items.Clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < taskList.Count; i++)
    {
        Tasks task = taskList.ElementAt(i);

        ListViewItem row = new ListViewItem();
        row.Text=task.date.ToString();
        row.SubItems.Add(task.job);
        row.SubItems.Add(task.clientName);
        row.SubItems.Add(task.submittedBy);

        listView1.Items.Add(row);
    }
}

public List<Tasks> getTasks()
{
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load("data.xml");

    XmlNodeList nodes = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/tasks/task");

    List<Tasks> taskList = new List<Tasks>();

    foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
    {
        Tasks task = new Tasks();
        task.id = Convert.ToInt32(node.SelectSingleNode("id").InnerText);
        task.date = Convert.ToDateTime(node.SelectSingleNode("submittedDate").InnerText);
        task.submittedBy = node.SelectSingleNode("submittedBy").InnerText;
        task.clientName = node.SelectSingleNode("clientName").InnerText;
        task.job = node.SelectSingleNode("job").InnerText;
        task.taskCategory = node.SelectSingleNode("taskCategory").InnerText;
        task.taskDescription = node.SelectSingleNode("taskDescription").InnerText;
        task.hours = node.SelectSingleNode("hours").InnerText;
        task.status = node.SelectSingleNode("status").InnerText;
        task.isBilled = node.SelectSingleNode("isBilled").InnerText;
        task.cost = node.SelectSingleNode("cost").InnerText;
        task.followUpInfo = node.SelectSingleNode("followUpInfo").InnerText;
        task.invoiceNumber = node.SelectSingleNode("quickBooksInvoiceNo").InnerText;

       taskList.Add(task);
    }

    return taskList;
}

private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

What I need is now how when I click an item from the `listView1` to show some value in a textbox? But that value should be taken from the list object `taskList`, not from the xml document itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store your `task ID` inside of your item's `Tag` property:

```
row.Tag = task.id;
```

Then handle `ListView.SelectedIndexChanged` event

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        var id = (int) listView1.SelectedItems[0].Tag;
        var currenTask = taskList.Where(t => t.id == id).First();
        textBox1.Text = currenTask.taskDescription; // for example
    }

}
```

Also you should define your `taskList` in the class level, outside of your `Form_Load` method.Otherwise you can't access it from `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

```
List<Tasks> taskList = new List<Tasks>();
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ...
}
```

Comment: What I need is to show somehow to the selectedIndexChanged that there is somewhere in the code a taskList....
I've tried with 
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e, List<Tasks> taskList) but no success. I also added the id in the ListViewItem row = new ListViewItem() ....

Comment: just do what I said.define it outside of form load method.Don't add extra column just use Tag property

Comment: When I click inside the listbox item, it doesn't even enter in the listView1_selectedIndexChange method

Comment: because you didn't attach the event handler.write this inside of your form load: `listView1.SelectedIndexChanged += listView1_SelectedIndexChanged;`

Comment: any idea how can i update the list object if i change the value from the textboxes if i click a Save button? also by updating the list, updating the xml itself